# how to test actor is main class with testkit in scala

Tags: scala, actor, mainclass, akka-testkit

I have started writing test for scala actor. I read this blog. http://blog.matthieuguillermin.fr/2013/06/akka-testing-your-actors/
Then I started. I wrote Application Actor. But I realized the application actor which is different others are in blog. Because the actor is as main class. It wrote string on console and sended message another actor. How can I test application actor?

```
    class Application extends Actor{

      val cliCommandExecute = context.actorOf(Props[CLICommandExecute],"CLICommandExecute")
      println(Util.welcomeMessage)
      cliCommandExecute ! CLICommandExecute.Listen(self)

      def receive = {
        case CLICommandExecute.Done(result: String) => {
          println(result)
          cliCommandExecute ! CLICommandExecute.Listen(self)
        }
        case CLICommandExecute.Failed(result: String) => {
          println(result)
          println(Util.failedMessage)
          context.stop(self)
        }
        case CLICommandExecute.Exit => {
          println(Util.exitMessage)
          context.stop(self)
        }
      }
    }
```

I wrote ApplicationTest. But when I run it, test results failed.

```
    class ApplicationTest  extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem"))
      with WordSpecLike
      with Matchers {

        "A application actor" must {
          // Creation of the TestActorRef
          val actorRef = TestActorRef[Application]
          val result = "success"
          "receive messages" in {
            // This call is synchronous. The actor receive() method will be called in the current thread
            actorRef ! CLICommandExecute.Done(result)
            // This method assert that the testActorRef has received a specific message
            expectMsg("success")
          }
        }
    }
```

Error is as follows:

```
    assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for success
    java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for success
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To get message by `expectMsg` here you should send response not to `cliCommandExecute`, but to `sender`:

```
  case CLICommandExecute.Done(result: String) => {
       println(result)
       cliCommandExecute ! CLICommandExecute.Listen(self)
  }
```

Change it to:

```
 case CLICommandExecute.Done(result: String) => {
      println(result)
      sender() ! CLICommandExecute.Listen(self)
 }
```

and you will receive response via `expectMsg`.

If you want to send response not to sender but to `cliCommandExecute` you should pass it as constructor parameter to your `Application` actor:

```
class Application(cliCommandExecute: ActorRef) extends Actor { ...}
```

and in your test pass `testActor` when you create it. In such a way all responses will be directed to `testActor` and you can get them via `expectMsg`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still error is given.Please, You enter command:success [INFO] [08/06/2015 15:40:09.069] [testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://testSystem/deadLetters] Message [com.console.app.CLICommandExecute$Listen] from TestActor[akka://testSystem/user/$$a] to Actor[akka://testSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for success

Comment: In normally program is working as I want to path. But I want to write test . In test there are errors